# find command with exec sh doesn't work in shell script but in commandline (raspberrypi)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, script, find

I want to find "old" folders in **/volume1/photo/ipcam** which are named like "????-??-??" and move corresponding folders within dropbox (with the same directory structure /ipcam/...) to the subfolder **/ipcam/archive**. The find command below (with the appropriate values used instead of the variables) works fine when used on the commandline but doesn't if used in a script:

via commandline:

```
find /volume1/photo/ipcam -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "????-??-??" -mtime +0 -exec sh -c 'echo /home/pi/Dropbox-Uploader/dropbox_uploader.sh move /ipcam/$(basename {}) /ipcam/archive' \;
```

via script:

```
#!/bin/bash    
path2disc="/volume1"
source="$path2disc/photo/ipcam"

dropboxtool="/home/pi/Dropbox-Uploader/dropbox_uploader.sh"
dropbox="/ipcam"
dropboxarchive="/ipcam/archive"

find $source -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "????-??-??" -mtime +0 -exec sh -c '$dropboxtool move $dropbox/$(basename {}) $dropboxarchive' \;
```

I think something is wrong with the quotes in the "script" version, but not sure.

PS: using the following version on the raspberrypi:
**Linux raspberrypi 3.10.24+ #614 PREEMPT Thu Dec 19 20:38:42 GMT 2013 armv6l GNU/Linux**

Comment: Variables don't get substituted inside single quotes. Try double quotes instead: `...-exec sh -c "$dropboxtool move ..." \;`. In your command line version you didn't used variables at all, so this worked.

Comment: thanks for your tip! You're right with the double quotes  **-exec sh -c "$dropboxtool move $dropbox/$(basename {}) $dropboxarchive" \;**. But now I have another problem with the statement in the script: The **$(basename {})** doesn't work correctly - instead of the name of the folder the whole pathname including the folder name has been substituted **/volume1/photo/ipcam/2014-02-20**. Do you have another tip to solve also this problem?

Comment: @mpy why don't you add your correct answer as a official answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

> I think something is wrong with the quotes in the "script" version, but not sure.

Yes, something is wrong: variables don't get substituted inside single-quotes. Just changing single- to double-quotes may work in your case, in some cases. It's *not the right thing* though.

In a comment you said `-exec sh -c "$dropboxtool move $dropbox/$(basename {}) $dropboxarchive" \;` works. Still this piece of code is badly flawed.

Problems:

1. [Never embed `{}` in the shell code!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618) That creates a command injection vulnerability. `find` mechanically substitutes `{}` and then `sh -c` interprets the result (along with the rest of the argument), possibly as code.
2. Similarly if you let the current shell substitute variables embedded in the shell code then `sh -c` will interpret the result possibly as code. Variables with characters like `;`, `>` or `|` may totally change what is about to be executed. You shouldn't do this unless:

   - injecting code from variables is what you explicitly want;
   - or you're absolutely sure the expanded variables are safe, but even then it's not a good practice.
3. Quote what should be quoted:

   - `$source` (just after `find` in your original code) [should be double-quoted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618).
   - There are two levels of quoting. In general certain strings should be quoted *in the context of the shell invoked by `find`*. This means the option-argument that gets to `sh -c` (after the outer shell removes the outer quotes) should *contain* some quotes, otherwise in some cases the code will break.

Your code should look more like this:

```
find "$source" -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "????-??-??" -mtime +0 -exec sh -c \
   '"$1" move "$2/$(basename "$4")" "$3"' \
   find-sh "$dropboxtool" "$dropbox" "$dropboxarchive" {} \;
```

Here `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, `$4` and `$( )` are not expanded by the current shell because they are single-quoted ([the outer quotes matter](https://superuser.com/q/1404244/432690)). The whole single-quoted string gets to the `sh -c` and only then these tokens are expanded. Note they are properly double-quoted at this level. Everything that needs to be substituted by the current shell or by `find` is passed to the inner shell as positional parameters after `find-sh` (explained [here](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690)), the code itself is static.